# @Named injection not working properly in dagger

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger-2

When I am injecting an object as below, it works properly

```
@Provides
@Singleton
    public CommandObject getCommandObject(final Command command) {
        ...
    }
```

But as soon as I add @Named to above it starts giving error

CommandObject cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

[`@Named`](http://javax-inject.github.io/javax-inject/api/javax/inject/Named.html) is a ["qualifier annotation"](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/#qualifiers) which usually takes a single String value as a parameter. This means that Dagger treats these three as [separate keys](https://dagger.dev/semantics/#keys):

```java
CommandObject
@Named("foo") CommandObject
@Named("bar") CommandObject
```

Once you add `@Named` to your CommandObject, it is no longer a simple unannotated CommandObject as far as Dagger is concerned, so Dagger tells you that one of your existing injection requests for CommandObject is missing its `@Provides` method. (The exact location of your request for a nameless CommandObject is in the full error message next to the "cannot be provided" description you posted in your question.)

- If you need more than one CommandObject in your graph and you want to distinguish them by name, add a matching `@Named` to the `@Inject` field or constructor parameter next to CommandObject.
- If you meant `@Named` just for documentation, remove it and use JavaDoc or another technique.
- Finally, if you'd rather not use a String to discern between CommandObjects, you can create your own Qualifier annotation like `@Named`, with the possibility of more parameters or IDE autocompletion. The [Dagger dev guide linked above](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/#qualifiers) provides instructions, including the simple definition of `@Named` itself for comparison's sake.

Answer (score 0):

The place where I was injecting the CommandObject to be used, Was not mentioning @Named there. Adding that fixed the issue

Earlier

```
@Inject
    public CreateObjectImpl(final ObjectMapper objectMapper,
                                 final CommandObject commandObject) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.commandObject = commandObject;
    }
```

After fix:

```
@Inject
    public CreateObjectImpl(final ObjectMapper objectMapper,
                                 @Named("commandObject") final CommandObject commandObject) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.commandObject = commandObject;
    }
```